# Pandas - Rename only first dictionary match instead of last match

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, indexing, python-3.6

I am trying to use pandas to rename a column in CSV files. I want to use a dictionary since sometimes columns with the same information can be named differently (e.g. mobile_phone and telephone instead of phone).

I want to rename the first instance of phone. Here is an example to hopefully explain more.

Here is the original in this example:

```
0 name     mobile_phone     telephone
1 Bob      12364234234      12364234234
2 Joe      23534235435      43564564563
3 Jill     34573474563      78098080807
```

Here is what I want it to do:

```
0 name     phone            telephone
1 Bob      12364234234      12364234234
2 Joe      23534235435      43564564563
3 Jill     34573474563      78098080807
```

This is the code I tried:

```
phone_dict = {
'phone_number': 'phone',
'mobile_phone': 'phone',
'telephone': 'phone',
'phones': 'phone',
}

if 'phone' not in df.columns:
df.rename(columns=dict(phone_dict), inplace=True)
if 'phone' not in df.columns:
    raise ValueError("What are these peoples numbers!? (Need 'phone' column)")
```

I made a dictionary with some possible column names and that I want them to be named 'phone'. However, when I run this code it turns the columns to this changes the second column instead of the first one that matches a key in the dictionary. I want it to stop after it matches the first column it comes across in the CSV.

This is what is happening:

```
0 name     mobile_phone     phone
1 Bob      12364234234      12364234234
2 Joe      23534235435      43564564563
3 Jill     34573474563      78098080807
```

If there is, for example, a third column that matches the dictionary they turn to 'phone' which is again not what I want. I am trying to get it to just change the first column it matches.

Here is an example of what happens when I add a third column. 
It goes from:

```
0 name     mobile_phone     telephone      phone_1
1 Bob      12364234234      12364234234    36346346311
2 Joe      23534235435      43564564563    34634634623
3 Jill     34573474563      78098080807    34634654622
```

To this:

```
0 name     phone            phone          phone
1 Bob      12364234234      12364234234    36346346311
2 Joe      23534235435      43564564563    34634634623
3 Jill     34573474563      78098080807    34634654622
```

But I want it to be this:

```
0 name     phone            telephone      phone_1
1 Bob      12364234234      12364234234    36346346311
2 Joe      23534235435      43564564563    34634634623
3 Jill     34573474563      78098080807    34634654622
```

Any advice or tips to stop it second changing the second dictionary match instead of the first one or all of them?

Before I had a bunch of elif statements but I thought a dictionary would be cleaner and easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't expect [`pd.DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) to apply any particular sequential ordering with a `dict` input. Even if the logic worked, it would be an implementation detail as the docs don't describe the actual process.

Instead, you can use [`pd.DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to find the first valid column label:

```
df = df.rename(columns={df.filter(like='phone').columns[0]: 'phone'})

print(df)

   0  name        phone    telephone
0  1   Bob  12364234234  12364234234
1  2   Joe  23534235435  43564564563
2  3  Jill  34573474563  78098080807
```

If it's possible a valid column may *not* exist, you can catch `IndexError`:

```
try:
    df = df.rename(columns={df.filter(like='phones').columns[0]: 'phone'})
except IndexError:
    print('No columns including "phones" exists.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

`df`:

```
Columns: [name, mobile_phone, telephone]
Index: []
```

Finding the first instance of phone (left to right) in the column index:

```
a = [True if ('phone' in df.columns[i]) & ('phone' not in df.columns[i-1]) else False for i in range(len(df.columns))]
```

Getting the column that needs to be renamed `phone`:

```
 phonecol = df.columns[a][0]
```

Renaming the column:

```
df.rename(columns = {phonecol : 'phone'})
```

Output:

```
Columns: [name, phone, telephone]
Index: []
```